# Does $\frac{1}{n}X_{n}$ converge in distribution to $X$ as $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Let $X$ be a random variable with $X \sim \operatorname{Exp}(\lambda)$ where $\lambda \in (0,1)$, and let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots$ be a sequence of real-valued random variables with $X_{n} \sim \operatorname{Geo}\left(\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Show that $\frac{1}{n}X_{n} \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{\longrightarrow} X$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

**Attempt/Idea:**

Use the following theorem to show convergence in distribution:

Theorem 3.3.6 Let $ \{X_{n}\}$, ${n \in \mathbb{N}}$, $X$ be random variables defined on the probability space $ (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P) $ with characteristic functions $ \varphi{X_{n}}, n \in \mathbb{N} $ and $ \varphi_{X} $. It holds that $ X_{n} \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\stackrel{d}{\rightarrow}} X $ if and only if
$
\varphi_{X_{n}}(t) \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{\longrightarrow} \varphi_{X}(t) \quad \forall t \in \mathbb{R}
$

Consider the characteristic function of $ X $ given by $ \phi_X(t) = \frac{\lambda}{\lambda - it} $.

And let us consider the characteristic function of ( X_n/n ) given by:
$$
 \phi_{X_n/n}(t) = E\left(e^{it(X_n/n)}\right) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{it(k/n)} \cdot \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{k-1} \cdot \frac{\lambda}{n} $$

If you set $r = e^{it\frac{1}{n}}$, then you have:

$$\frac{\lambda}{n} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} r^k \cdot \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^{k-1} 
= \frac{\lambda}{n} \cdot r \cdot \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  \left(r \cdot (1-\frac{\lambda}{n})\right)^{k}
= \frac{\lambda}{n} \cdot e^{it \cdot \frac{1}{n}} \cdot \frac{1}{1-(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}) \cdot e^{it \cdot \frac{1}{n}}}$$

(From here I get a little stuck on how to now further transform and whether the characteristic function of X_n also converges to X. Can someone help me further?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All we have left is to show that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}n\left(1-\left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)\cdot e^{it/n}\right)=\lambda-it$$
With a substitution, this is equivalent to evaluating
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\left(1-(1-\lambda x)\cdot e^{itx}\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\left(1-(1-\lambda x)(1+itx+o(x))\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\left(1-(1+itx+o(x)-\lambda x-\lambda itx^2-o(x^2))\right)$$
$$=\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac{1}{x}\left(-itx+\lambda x+o(x))\right)$$
$$=\lambda-it$$
as desired.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with o-Notation, so I would appreciate a different approach to show exactly this.

Comment: @clementine1001 At the point we change it to a limit as $x\to 0$, you can just recognize it as a derivative.  (Some people may think "L'Hopital", but it's quite literally just the definition of a derivative)

Comment: oh yes that also works. I hadn't realized that oops I overcomplicated that